# Cannot swipe back after swipping from 1st screen to 2nd screen and back to 1st screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am running the most basic Tab bar navigation [example from the react-navigation docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-top-tab-navigator#example) example. The tab navigator has three screens (Feed, Updates and Profile). I can swipe between the screens or press on tabs to navigate between the screens.

- The problem:

  1. Suppose I am on the 1st screen (Home screen)
  2. Touch the screen to swipe, and remember ***Don't let go of the finger, until it is advised***.
  3. Swipe left to navigate to the 2nd screen (Update Screen). **Don't let go of the finger**.
  4. Before reaching the 2nd screen, swipe back right (all the way to the end of the screen or till the tab indicator is back to the 1st screen) to come back to the 1st screen. Still **don't let go of the finger**.
  5. Now again, try to swipe left to navigate to the 2nd screen (Update Screen). *It cannot swipe left again to the 2nd screen (update Screen)*.

  GIF of the problem:   [image]

  It seems like the swiping is disabled when resettling back to the screen. This happens only on the first tab and last tab (left most and right most screens). Tested on both the actual device and on the emulator.

  Also, it does not have an *over-swiping effect* when reaching the edge of the screen.
- Expected Behavior

  I was expecting while my fingers are touching, after I swipe left from 1st screen to 2nd screen, and swiping right back to 1st screen, I could swipe left again to navigate to 2nd screen.

  Working Example: [image]

  As you can see from the above example, it has the *over-swiping effect*. Also, I can swipe left from 1 screen to 2nd screen, swipe right back again to 1st screen till I reach the edge of the screen, and again swipe left to 2nd screen.
- How to reproduce

  1. As described above.
  2. React navigation material top tab example app on [Snack](https://snack.expo.io/?platform=android&name=Tab%20navigation%20%7C%20React%20Navigation&dependencies=%40expo%2Fvector-icons%40*%2C%40react-native-community%2Fmasked-view%40*%2C%40react-navigation%2Fbottom-tabs%40%5E5.8.0%2C%40react-navigation%2Fdrawer%40%5E5.9.0%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-bottom-tabs%40%5E5.2.16%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-top-tabs%40%5E5.2.16%2C%40react-navigation%2Fnative%40%5E5.7.3%2C%40react-navigation%2Fstack%40%5E5.9.0%2Creact-native-paper%40%5E4.0.1%2Creact-native-reanimated%40*%2Creact-native-safe-area-context%40*%2Creact-native-gesture-handler%40*%2Creact-native-screens%40*%2Creact-native-tab-view%40%5E2.15.1&hideQueryParams=true&sourceUrl=https%3A%2F%2Freactnavigation.org%2Fexamples%2F5.x%2Fmaterial-top-tab-example.js)
- Version

  1. @react-navigation/native   ^5.9.4
  2. @react-navigation/material-top-tabs    ^5.3.15